# Strip newline characters and quotes from JSON array and set specific strings as variables via bash

Tags: bash, sed, jq

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "Name": "No.reply",
    "Email": "no.reply@xxxxxx.com",
    "ID": 5930,
    "details": 
    {
        "message": "Your name: john doe\nEmail: johndoe@xxxxxxx.com\nSubject: I need help with this\nDescription: I can find the download for the manual but I can only find the free updater for Windows or Mac. Can you help me please as I have a chrome notebook and Moto smart phone. Thank you. John doe"
    }
}
```

The name and email fields from the top level are irrelevant, as they are from the automated email. The information I need is in the message field and in the ID field, which is related to John Doe's info.

Anyway, this is what I need to be filtered and how it should be saved to a new file in this order:

- **Name:** it should read the lines after this variable, regardless of the text.
- **Email:** same as above
- **Subject:** same as above
- **Description:** same as above
- **ID:** same as above

So, I need to remove the quotes, the newline character, assign those specific strings to a variable via bash, and read what it's after those strings.

I was able to come up with something, but it doesn't work for this JSON output: (only works if the text file is properly formatted)

```
while IFS=''
do  case "$line" in
    "Name:"*)             uservar="${line#*: }" ;;
    "Email:"*)            emailvar="${line#*: }" ;;
    "Subject:"*)          subject="${line#*: }" ;;
    "Message:"*)          message="${line#*: }" ;;
    "ID:"*)        ticketidvar="${line#*: }" ;;
    esac
done <<-EOF
$(pbpaste)
EOF
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  That JSON seems malformed -- are you sure there's not a comma after `"ID": 5930`?

Comment: use this https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor to validate your json data.

Comment: Hi to both.  Thank you for your suggestions. I have now added a comma and validated the JSON data accordingly.

Comment: You've said that the `details` field is irrelevant, but you appear to want to extract "your name", "subject" and "description" from `message`, which is inside `details`.  Which is true?  And which email do you want: the top-level `Email` member ("no.reply") or the one inside `message` ("johndoe")?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question again to better explain what I want. The info I need is in the `message`, so I'll need the `Email` info inside `message` (john doe). The no.reply information is to be ignored. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes that the `Description: ...` part of the message is a single line, and that the headers are in the canonical form (no `" subJECT :hey"`, please).

It's using `jq`'s `@sh` format spec to escape its output in a manner suitable for the shell (with single quotes). Thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas for corrections.

```
parse_json(){
  jq=$(jq -r '[.Email,.ID,(.details.message | split("\n")) | @sh] | join(" ")' -- "$1")
  eval "set -- $jq"
  email=$1; shift
  id=$1; shift
  for l; do
    case $l in
    "Your name: "*) name="${l#*: }";;
    "Subject: "*) subject="${l#*: }";;
    "Description: "*) description="${l#*: }";;
    # remove the following line if you want the .Email from json instead
    "Email: "*) email="${l#*: }";;
    esac
  done
  echo "id={$id}"
  echo "name={$name}"
  echo "email={$email}"
  echo "subject={$subject}"
  echo "description={$description}"
}

fz:/tmp% parse_json a.json
id={5930}
name={john doe}
email={johndoe@xxxxxxx.com}
subject={I need help with this}
description={I can find the download for the manual but I can only find the free updater for Windows or Mac. Can you help me please as I have a chrome notebook and Moto smart phone. Thank you. John doe
```

The `case ... esac` above could be replaced with something that will create variables with the same names as the headers with the non-alphanumeric characters replaced by underscores. This will only work with shells that support `${var//pat/repl}` substitutions(`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh93`):

```
parse_json(){
  jq=$(jq -r '[.Email,.ID,(.details.message | split("\n")) | @sh] | join(" ")' -- "$1")
  eval "set -- $jq"
  Email=$1; shift
  ID=$1; shift
  for l; do
    v="${l#*: }"; k="${l%%: *}"; eval "${k//[!a-zA-Z0-9]/_}=\$v"
  done
}

show_vars(){
  for v in ID Your_name Email Subject Description; do
    eval "echo \"$v=[\$$v]\""
  done
}

fz:/tmp$ parse_json a.json
fz:/tmp$ show_vars
ID=[5930]
Your_name=[john doe]
Email=[johndoe@xxxxxxx.com]
Subject=[I need help with this]
Description=[I can find the download for the manual but I can only find the free updater for Windows or Mac. Can you help me please as I have a chrome notebook and Moto smart phone. Thank you. John doe]
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your help. One very noobish question: How do I run this code? Can I create a bash script with it?

Comment: you should insert the parse_json() function in your script, with the `echo ...` lines deleted. When called as in the example, it will set set the `name`, `email`, `subject`, etc variables. Don't run it in a subcommand/subprocess. Notice that you'll have to modify it if you want the `email` to be that from the message instead of that from the top json object.

Comment: @HV83 I've updated the example to set the email to the one from inside the message, and added another one that generates variables based on the header names (`Your name` => `$Your_name`, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an associative array:

```
typeset -A field="($(jq -r '
   "[ID]=" + (.ID|@sh),
   (.details.message|capture("(?m)^(?<t>.*?): (?<v>.*)"; "g")|
     "["+(.t|@sh)+"]="+(.v|@sh))' file.json))"
```

Then you'd have the ID in  `${field[ID]}`, subject in `${field[Subject]}`...

On your sample, `typeset -p field` outputs:

```
declare -A fields=(
  [Description]="I can find the download for the manual but I can only find the free updater for Windows or Mac. Can you help me please as I have a chrome notebook and Moto smart phone. Thank you. John doe"
  [ID]="5930"
  [Subject]="I need help with this"
  [Email]="johndoe@xxxxxxx.com"
  ["Your name"]="john doe"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but if the intention is to create variables out of the contents of `.details.message` I would suggest the following.

First extract `.details.message` in raw mode with `jq`:

```
jq -r '.details.message' in.json
```

Now parse this with `sed` to make it bash-parsable:

*parse.sed*

```sed
/^Your name: /   s//uservar="/
/^Email: /       s//emailvar="/
/^Subject: /     s//subject="/
/^Description: / s//message="/
s/$/"/
```

Now you can source this in your script, e.g.:

```
. <(jq -r '.details.message' in.json | sed -f parse.sed)
echo $uservar, $emailvar
```

Output:

```
john doe, johndoe@xxxxxxx.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so sophisticated (I suppose the shown text is in some file let us say `json.txt` or you can send the text to the first `sed` through a pipe):

`sed s/'$'/:/ json.txt |\`   ... add a `:` at the end of each line

`sed s/'\\n'/:/g       |\`   ... change any `\n` to `:`

`sed s/'"'//g          |\`   ... remove quots

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="}";FS=":"}{if($7){print "Name: "$3"\nEmail: "$5"\nSubject: "$17"\nDescription: "$19"\nID: "$7}}'
```

In `awk` set the row separator to `}`, field separator to `:` and compose your output. There may left some ending commas, you can easily remove.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all you need is the decoded `.details.message` string followed by a line with the ID:

```bash
jq -r '.details.message, "ID: \(.ID)"' file >outfile
```

This decodes the `.details.message` string and adds a separate line with the value of the top-level `.ID` key, prefixed by `ID:` .

For the given JSON document, this would generate the following output in the file `outfile`:

```
Your name: john doe
Email: johndoe@xxxxxxx.com
Subject: I need help with this
Description: I can find the download for the manual but I can only find the free updater for Windows or Mac. Can you help me please as I have a chrome notebook and Moto smart phone. Thank you. John doe
ID: 5930
```